# which file is executed first when psql terminal started

Tags: postgresql, psql

In Postgresql their is command prompt psql Now the question is I want to some script automatically loaded when I start the psql command prompt

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#id-1.9.4.18.10

Comment: you tell me the location of that file I am using ubuntu operating system

Comment: The location of that file is documented in the section of the manual from my link

Comment: @PraveenMourya, in case you didn't know in unix shells ~ is an alias for your home directory

Comment: Thank you @Eelke